# Can we get an additional moderator for Stack Apps?

Tags: support, status-completed, moderation, moderators, stackapps

Currently, [Stack Apps has only one moderator](https://stackapps.com/about#footer), [Nathan Osman](https://stackapps.com/users/18/nathan-osman).  He's good when he's around, but he's sometimes gone from Stack Apps for days at a time.

For example, [it's been 2 days since he last visited any SE site](https://stackexchange.com/users/65895/nathan-osman?tab=accounts); and Stack Apps has [off](https://stackapps.com/q/4078/7653)  [topic](https://stackapps.com/q/4081/7653), and even [spam](https://stackapps.com/q/4085/7653)<sup>1</sup> questions lying about.  (Plus edits and flags)

Can we get at least one more moderator?  Stack Apps is low traffic (0.9 questions per day), but I figure a mod should check on it at least once a day.  (And, yes, I volunteer -- or please setup elections.)

---

<sup>1</sup> Update 1:  The spam post has now been removed, probably by finally getting enough spam flags (it took about a day).

---

Update 2:
Dredged up today's stats for all SE sites that either had less traffic than Stack Apps or had fewer questions per day.  Here they are:

```
Site                        Visits   Questions  Community
                            per day  per day    Moderators
==========================  =======  =========  ==========
Project Management            1600      0.8          3
Spanish Language & Usage       995      0.5          3
The Great Outdoors             882      0.6          3
LEGO® Answers                  770      0.6          3
Programming Puzzles & Code     638      0.9          3
**=> Stack Apps <=**           478      0.8     **=> 1 <=**
English Language Learners      394     12.0          3
Martial Arts                   390      0.7          3
Reverse Engineering            366      2.3          3
Robotics                       312      1.1          3
Chess                          284      1.4          3
Chinese Language & Usage       278      1.1          3
Tridion                        272      5.4          3
Libraries & Information Sc     177      0.3          3
Politics                       164      0.9          3
Russian Language & Usage       164      0.6          3
Poker                          154      0.4          3
SmugMug                        140      0.3          3
Genealogy & Family History     127      0.9          3
```

It seems that Stack Apps may be unique among all the sites in having only one *Community* moderator.  And, since it's an established site, that's been around longer, it seems like [a bigger target for unsavory posts][7].

Comment: Is this really a problem? There are a ton of SE employees with diamonds with lots of reputation on the site and presumably this means they're using it. (OTOH, there are only 17 ordinary 3K users, so regular voting to close looks difficult to accomplish)

Comment: @Wooble, yes it's a problem, perhaps not a big one, but it's also easily rectified.  There have been about 3 times, over the last year-ish, when the site has gone unmoderated for at least 2 days.  That's just what I noticed and I don't normally visit that site daily.

Comment: Maybe a *Please visit the site daily* to the mod would be good enough...

Comment: No mod should be expected to visit the site daily @juergend, there are holidays and broken telephone lines and long days at work to consider.

Comment: Ewww, can we please remove that disgusting looking man from the 404 page too?

Comment: @animuson I second that

Comment: @animuson Don't judge him simply because he's not wearing a holster.

Comment: I support this guy becoming a mod there for the sole reason that he has a rainbow spitting fire unicorn. Brings whole new meaning to the term "unicorns are just weaponized ponies".

Comment: I think we should force TimeStone to moderate this one. TimeStone for Triangle! Triangle Tim Stone they always used to call him, back when he was almost a mod, or TTs for short.

Comment: @jcolebrand And here, I thought you were repeatedly making a typo!

Comment: Sorry, everyone. I had a very busy week - much busier than I was expecting.

Comment: I  also agree that the 404 page needs changing. It's... very disturbing to say the least.

Comment: @NathanOsman, no one expects you to be on call every day.  And, thank you for volunteering at all.  But, the *public* stats show that you have a disproportionate burden moderating that site.

Comment: Instead of commenting further, I have posted an answer below.

Comment: What the hell is SmugMug SE?

Comment: @Randal'Thor, *Was*: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/25069/smugmug

Comment: Oh wow, that's an actual thing. I thought it was some kind of joke.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Stack Apps is unique in that it's more of a showcase for applications written around our API and a resource to find libraries to interact with it. The site sees only *marginal* flag activity, and the current moderator does a pretty good job of staying on top of the flags and janitorial work the site creates.

What the site does *not* have is a default contact in the community team, since it's rather different - there didn't seem to be a need to add one. We've assigned one, thus guaranteeing that at *least* one employee will be stopping by the site daily in addition to the moderator keeping an eye on it. Thus, nothing should go without being handled for too long.

As for another moderator - the site could *conceivably* sustain an election, but I really doubt that there would be any kind of turn out - we'd probably end up giving diamonds to the one (or two) people that bothered to nominate. If flag activity starts to warrant more help, we'll revisit it then.

**Update**

Because we know he'll do an excellent job, and because [he seems to *want* it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179683/can-we-get-an-additional-moderator-for-stack-apps/179727#comment544315_179727), we're appointing Tim Stone as a moderator on Stack Apps to add his skills and some redundancy to the team. Tim will be receiving his diamond shortly and going forth into Stack Apps moderation awesomeness.

Comment: Yeah, there doesn't really seem to be much of a community there other than maybe 10-15 regulars.

Comment: I doubt we'd try to run an election there. We'd probably just appoint another regular if there was a need.

Comment: C'mon, you know you want to hook a fellow Tim up. *wink wink nudge nudge*

Comment: I wholeheartedly and enthusiastically second Tim Stone's nomination!

Comment: If Tim can't do it, no one can.

Comment: Thanks, Tim.  Still have at least 1 unhandled flag and 1 unhandled suggested-edit. But it sounds like they'll be addressed in the next day?

Comment: @AwesomePoodles I just took care of those.

Comment: I sorted [the public traffic data](http://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic), and it turns out that there are 13 other active sites, with less traffic than Stack Apps.  And yet, every other site seems to have at least 3 community moderators.

Comment: @AwesomePoodles It's not really just traffic, it's the flag volume that broadly determines how many mods a site really needs. StackApps gets an almost _less_ than negligible amount, it just doesn't make sense to add another mod at this point. But if that changes, or the existing mod indicates that he needs some help, we can easily appoint another mod on the site.

Comment: @TimPost, We can't see flag-volume statistics; can you show us some? Other than that, I hear you.  I'm not sure what it hurts to bring that site up to parity (other than the small risk of getting a bad mod), but you've stated a reasonable plan and assigned a default contact, and that may be enough.

Comment: @AwesomePoodles The enthusiasm behind this is rather compelling, we're going to talk about it on Monday. As for volume, at _most_ the site receives three flags per day, with many days none at all. Additional mods wouldn't really have much to do (flag wise) if added.

Comment: Thanks, @TimPost.  Trying not to nag, but how does that 0-3 flags, a day, compare to the other low-traffic sites?

Comment: @AwesomePoodles Averages aren't exact science, but Stack Apps sees way more 0 -1 days (many just 0) than it does 1 - 3 compared with other smaller sites. It's also a special use site. But as I noted, the enthusiasm expressed here has been heard, we're going to talk about it internally on Monday. I'll update here again once we have.

Comment: @AwesomePoodles: note that sites with less traffic are expected to grow. Stack Apps -- not so much.

Comment: Upon discussing it as a team, we've decided that some additional redundancy definitely can't _hurt_, and @TimStone is more than qualified to step up and do the job. He's been appointed - as I stated earlier an election really isn't feasible for Stack Apps at this time.

Comment: Bwuah...I mean, nifty, thanks! :o I will naturally show those flags no mercy.

Comment: Thanks Tim Post and congrats, @TimStone! I'll be happy to send you a userscript to auto-approve all my flags and suggested edits, if you like. :)

Answer (score 26):

First off, I'd like to just clarify exactly what happened: I had an extremely busy week at work. Now normally this doesn't affect my ability to moderate since I am still around during the evening. However, everything just piled up to create the perfect storm and the only time I was able to much of anything was Tuesday evening (I closed a couple of posts).

As Tim has already stated, the site receives a relatively low number of flags - enough that one person could easily deal with them. Also, the *vast* majority of off-topic questions on the site are from users who are confused by the name of the website (Stack *Apps*). Dealing with these questions is easy enough, but I wouldn't be opposed to a name change if it were determined that this would result in much fewer off-topic questions.

If it is decided that another moderator is needed, I would certainly welcome him / her and their assistance - but I really don't see a huge need for that at this point.

Perhaps a better option would be to *lower the rep. requirement for closing questions.* As has also been mentioned, there are a pitiful number of users with >3k rep. It would be great if more users were able to vote for closing questions. As of today, changing the requirement to 1k rep. would result in 49 additional users being able to vote to close questions.

As always, please continue to flag as usual and I will continue to process flags as best as I can.