# Replace the picture of the half-naked man on the 404 page of Stackapps

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, 404-not-found, stackapps

Currently, the [404 page on Stackapps](https://stackapps.com/404) looks like this: [censored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KA2ro.png).

To me, it seems a little.. strange to see a half-naked guy with a gun on what is supposed to be "professional" site, and it's not really something I'd like to come across with my boss (or my parents..) looking over my shoulder. The [CMs agree with me too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179683/can-we-get-an-additional-moderator-for-stack-apps?rq=1#comment544121_179683):

[image]

Can we get rid of this guy and replace him with something else ?

Comment: That guy is Sean Connery in Zardoz.  The world would be a better place if that entire film was 404.

Comment: I think everyone must be reminded of how horrible the 70's were.  Be glad you didn't live through them.

Comment: I have this photo printed out on my office door and now I'm sad

Comment: The photo @KasraRahjerdi has was handed down from me.

Comment: @Kasra why? You just realised it's a picture of half naked man? ;)

Comment: Which half offends you?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Nope, I love half-naked men (esp 70s Connery), i'm just sad we might have to change it!

Comment: @Kasra don't give up! You're strong! :-D

Comment: When did StackApps become a "professional" site? Why are you browsing the site during work hours in the first place?

Comment: @JasonPunyon the pic is 404 now, was it [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fb5ht.jpg)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So while I was <s>spying on</s> hanging out in the design channel, this picture came up again and reignited disgust for some people.

It has now been removed from the page. Rest in peace, Zed...

[image: Sean Connery as Zed in Zardoz]

...May you always patrol the unfound wastelands of our hearts.

Comment: Expect down votes from Sean Connery fans ...

Comment: @rene or from people who don't like SE not taking a stand on this... (Come on... it's just humor...)

Comment: Zed's dead baby, Zed's dead.

Comment: Given the first comment in the screenshot in the question, I don't imagine that animuson is going to be happy about @Shog's edit...

Comment: Note everyone can make a loincloth and bandoliers out of an orange curtain. :-)