# Stack Apps offline page with 007 image

Tags: discussion, stackapps, offline, maintenance

Just before I got the offline page for the [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/) site.

Along with the following warning message

> Stack Apps is currently offline for maintenance
>   Routine maintenance usually takes less than an hour. If this turns into an extended outage, we will tweet updates from @StackStatus or post details on the status blog.

the image below also showing in that page. The 007 image looks like it related to [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) site.

Is the image wrongly placed for the StackApps offline page? or they meant the Stack Apps is for super special activities like the 007 ?

Screenshot for reference:

[image: StackApps offline page showing 007 image]

Comment: Would you prefer the old Zardoz picture? - http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/280328/236563

Comment: Be glad.  http://stackapps.com/404